# Several errors with C++ helloworld program

Tags: c++

I am trying to teach myself C++ with an old book I've had lying around and have multiple errors trying to run the initial HelloWorld program as written in community visual studio 2017. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream.h>

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run the program, I get the following errors:

[image: C++ errors]

Comment: `#include <iostreamh>` (no `.h`). `std::cout`. Your C++ textbook is out of date by some twenty years.

Comment: "I am trying to teach myself C++ with an old book". That's the problem. The book is too old. Recycle it.

Comment: Its `#include <iostream>` there was a typo above

Answer (score 5):

I assume you have a book about Turbo C++? Ditch it and try one of [**a good C++ books**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead.

A well written HelloWorld in C++ looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0; //optional
}
```

Comment: endl is also optional, and discouraged (by e.g. C++ Core Guidelines)

Comment: It's "Teach Yourself C++ in 21 Days", published 1997. I knew it was old, but it was something I already owned. Guess i'll be ponying up for one of those new books.

Comment: @DezM C++ standard was created in 1998, so yeah, I'd strongly recommend a newer book to learn. You won't learn C++ from pre-standard books.

Comment: @Cubbi I agree, but it's readablity vs. performance here. Flushing stream is not much of a deal in such short program, and `std::endl` is easier to read than "\n" IMO. We could omit it fully as well.

Answer (score -2):

There are two ways to do it. I wrote code in  VS2017,
1.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

2.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

for your reference
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout
I highly recommend you 
[https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Principles-Practice-Using-C/dp/0321543726](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321543726)

Comment: `#include "stdafx.h"` Nope

Comment: Direct link to a shop might be seen as spam. I'd rather post author, title and relevant information allowing finding the book on your own.

Comment: @George : could you explain why ?

Comment: It's wholly unnecessary for that program, and is a pch convention specific to windows/vs.

Answer (score -3):

Use as "< iostream>".You can also use search functionality to check if similar question is asked :)